# Will an iron sphere covered all over with little neodymium magnets become a magnet monopole?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles, ferromagnetism

As iron reacts with magnets producing a field dependent on magnet's pole orientation should an iron sphere when covered with little magnets which nord poles aim towards the center of the sphere become nothing less than a monopole with spawning south poles lines outwards?